# WordDelimiterFilterFactory not including all permutations

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a Solr index that has to deal with part numbers - which the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` seems ideally suited for. An example part number could be "CH2300-100". I'm expecting the following queries to match this field (and they do):

- CH
- CH2300-100
- CH2300100

But the following query doesn't match:

- CH2300

Looking at the debugging output - that combination of word parts isn't generated. I expected the `catenateWords` and/or `catenateNumbers` attribute to handle this case but it seems not to work. Am I missing something in the configuration that would allow all permutations of the tokenized fragments to be matched?

```xml
<schema version="1.5" name="test">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field stored="true" name="id" type="text" />
    <field stored="true" indexed="true" name="catnum" type="text" />
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that 'CH2300' is not an indexed token because splitOnNumerics="1". At the split phase, it separates CH and 2300 and then it applies all of the generators to those individually (as well as to the catenated tokens).

One option is to add splitOnNumerics="0" to your filter factory. However, that may keep 'CH' from matching. Another option is to add a filter factory at query time that splits on numerics.

**Edit**

A third and possibly better option is to use a [shingle filter factory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory) and to leave splitOnNumerics="1" so that all of CH, 2300, and CH2300 get indexed. Adding this line after your word delimiter filter factory should solve the problem:

`<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" tokenSeparator=""/>`

Comment: Interesting. The first two solutions break existing functionality (as you noted), but I like the last one very much. My only concern is that if I apply this to a field that contains more than just the part number (ie a part number embedded in free text) I'll end up with erroneous tokens from the shingle filter. Is there a way to apply that filter conditionally (perhaps only if the delimiter filter generated extra tokens)?

Comment: If you're worried about it breaking a field other than catnum, you could create a new fieldType for the other field that doesn't have the shingle filter factory. If you are worried about breaking other values of the catnum field, the solution gets more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What's the gist of the complicated solution? Writing a custom filter?

Comment: No problem! Yeah, a custom filter would work. Or you could do some pre-processing outside of Solr (depending on your level of control over document submission). I thought of another solution, which only works if your part numbers can be described by a regex. Basically, add a pattern filter factory after the tokenizer to make sure that only part-numbers get indexed.